# Gradle lazy Exec-Task configuration

Tags: kotlin, gradle, properties, lazy-initialization, gradle-task

I'm running into a problem when configuring an Exec-Task using an Extension-Property.

#### Problem

The configuration of my Exec-Task relies on a String-Property that is defined in an extension. Unfortunately, the property is not set yet, when configuring the Exec-Task. This leads to an `TaskCreationException`:

```
Could not create task ':myTask'.
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':myTask'.
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of extension 'myConfig' property 'command' because it has no value available.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:86)
```

#### Example

```kotlin
abstract class ConfigExtension() {
    abstract val command: Property<String>
}

class MyGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val myConfig = project.extensions.create(
            "myConfig",
            ConfigExtension::class.java
        )

        val myTask = project.tasks.register(
            "myTask",
            Exec::class.java
        ) {
            it.commandLine(myConfig.command.get())
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the `myConfig.command.get()` which circumvents the lazy evaluation.

#### Test

```kotlin
@Test fun `plugin registers task`() {
    // Create a test project and apply the plugin
    val project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    project.plugins.apply("com.example.plugin")

    // Verify the result
    assertNotNull(project.tasks.findByName("myTask"))
}
```

#### Question

Is there a way to configure the `commandLine`-Value in a lazy manner like gradle tasks should be configured? [[1]](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) [[2]](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `Exec` task's properties like `executable`, `args`, or `commandLine` (which sets the former two), are not yet accepting `Provider`s.

But the values are lazily evaluated using `toString()` when needed. So to be more lazy, you could supply some object that lazily evaluates the extension's property in its `toString()` method.

But actually, this would not change anything in your case.
You properly leverage task configuration avoidance.
So the extension property is only evaluated when your `Exec` task is configured.
So as long as nothing else in your build breaks task configuration avoidance for that task, you should be fine.

The problem is your test, which does not configure the extension, but then causes the task to be realized and configured by using `findByName`.

You should probably either define some convention for the extension property, so that it is not unset, or set a value in your test before querying the task.

Answer (score 0):

There are `jvmArgumentProviders` in `JavaExec` and `argumentProviders` in `Exec`.
One can use them like so:

```kotlin
jvmArgumentProviders.add { listOf("-Dfoo.bar=${lazyFooBar()}") }
```

There is also another trick: arguments are evaluated lazily using `toString()`. So you can add an object to args list with `toString()` method calculated lazily to the value you need.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP tries to set `commandLine` which cannot be supplied using a `jvmArgumentProvider`.

Comment: one can set `commandLine` to just binary and pass everything else via provider, don't  they?

Comment: Yes, one could, or rather one should set `executable` instead in that case. But that was not the question. OP shows `commandLine` with one argument which then is treated as the `executable` and thus cannot be provided using `jvmArgumentProviders`.

Comment: then a workaround might be to call `sh -c` or `cmd /K` and pass the app as a parameter